# Doctrine parameters issue

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have the following piece of code that is giving the following exception and I can't figure out why, any help would be appreciated.

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens

```
if (!empty($ids)) {
            $queryIds = implode(",", $ids);
            $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
                        ->select('p')
                        ->where('p.id >= :rand')
                        ->where('p.id NOT IN (:ids)')
                        ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
                        ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
                        ->setParameter('ids', $queryIds)
                        ->setMaxResults(1);
        } else {
            $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
                ->select('p')
                ->where('p.id >= :rand')
                ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
                ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
                ->setMaxResults(1);
        }
        try {
            if($options['videos'] == "off"){
                $query->where("p.type <> :type")->setParameter("type",1);
            }
            if($options['sfw'] == "on"){
                $query->where("p.safeForWork <> :sfw")->setParameter("sfw",0);
            }
            $post = $query->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
            $post = null;
        }
```

Comment: To avoid you try {} catch {} block, you can use the `->getOneOrNullResult()` method.

Comment: Maybe try to use andWhere or orWhere?

Comment: @Schwierig yes you are correct. Just changed from ZF and that's how I used to do it there. If you put this comment as an answer I will happily accept it. Thank you.

Comment: PR was faster than I was, you can accept his answer ;)

Comment: @Schwierig , sorry for that! I did not pay attention to those comments before I posted. From what I see, you answered before. Post you answer too pls. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above in the comments the problems lies with the double usage of `->where` in your querybuilder. If you want to combine multiple where clauses you need to use `->andWhere` or/and `->orWhere`.

Also I changed your result to `->getOneOrNullResult()`, with that you don't need to use this whole try/catch block you used to catch the doctrine exception.

```
if (!empty($ids)) {
    $queryIds = implode(",", $ids);
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
        ->select('p')
        ->where('p.id >= :rand')
        ->where('p.id NOT IN (:ids)')
        ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
        ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
        ->setParameter('ids', $queryIds)
        ->setMaxResults(1);
} else {
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
        ->select('p')
        ->where('p.id >= :rand')
        ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
        ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
        ->setMaxResults(1);
}

if($options['videos'] == "off"){
    $query->where("p.type <> :type")->setParameter("type",1);
}
if($options['sfw'] == "on"){
    $query->where("p.safeForWork <> :sfw")->setParameter("sfw",0);
}

$post = $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is the problem. Your query should look like this

```
if (!empty($ids)) {
    $queryIds = implode(",", $ids);
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
                ->select('p')
                ->where('p.id >= :rand')
                ->andWhere('p.id NOT IN (:ids)')
                ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
                ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
                ->setParameter('ids', $queryIds)
                ->setMaxResults(1);
} else {
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('MainClientBundle:Posts','p')
        ->select('p')
        ->where('p.id >= :rand')
        ->orderBy('p.id','ASC')
        ->setParameter('rand', rand(1, $max))
        ->setMaxResults(1);
}
try {
    if($options['videos'] == "off"){
        $query->where("p.type <> :type")->setParameter("type",1);
    }
    if($options['sfw'] == "on"){
        $query->where("p.safeForWork <> :sfw")->setParameter("sfw",0);
    }
    $post = $query->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
} catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
    $post = null;
}
```

Note that I changed your second where to andWhere. When you use two where() in the same query builder, the first gets overwritten by the second.